# Getting data from C++ into Python with memcpy

Tags: python, c++, com

I am trying to interface with a large piece of software written in C++ at my workplace.  The standard interface for this software is the Microsoft COM interface and I have managed to 'Dispatch' the interface appropriately using win32com.  I can run inbuilt methods and can get data that is explicitly returned by the C++ function.

I am struggling with a few functions in the C++ code that do not return the data, instead requiring a memory address and using memcpy to transfer the variables to the previously allocated memory.

```
void RetrieveData::GetData( long FAR* Data ){
    memcpy( Data, m_pMeasureData, m_MeasureDataSize * sizeof( long ) );
}
```

This is the C++ function in question which I call in python like so:

```
import array
import win32com.Client
IRD = win32com.client.Dispatch("Instrument.RetrieveData")

#Creating and Array of longs
arrayOfLongs = array.array('l')

#Init the list to be 25 items long with all 0 value
#I know the data is 25 items long from other functions
arrayOfLongs.fromlist([0]*25)

Data = IRD.GetData(arrayOfLongs)
```

I am left with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
    IRD.GetData(arrayOfLongs)
  File "<COMObject Instrument.RetrieveData>", line 2, in GetData
TypeError: Internal error - the buffer length is not the sequence length!
```

How can I create an array for the C++ function to memcpy to?

Thanks

Greg :)

Comment: Try adding `Data = new [ m_MeasureDataSize * sizeof( long )];` before memcpy

Comment: I cannot trivially change the C++ code as it is part of a much larger program at work. I will edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Try this: `import array; arr = array.array('c', ['\0' for _ in xrange(100)])` and pass arr to your c++ function. Alternatively if data is not very large, you can write it to a file in c++ code and read the file in python code.